# angular loop through unnamed ng-form elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-form, angularjs-view

Is there a way to loop through unnamed ng-form elements in my view?

```
<div ng-controller="CtrlMain as vm">
    <ng-form>
        <input name="Email" type="text" />
    </ng-form>
    <ng-form>
        <input name="PhoneNumber" type="text" />
    </ng-form>
</div>
```

My goal is to loop through each ng-form and then each input.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such posibility. `ng-form` creates fields in object which corresponds to names passed to `<input>` tags.